# PID re-use, edge case?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, pid

I read that PID reuse is done when process is zombie and was waited for.

What happens if I forked hundreds of processes and just killed the parent without waiting for them? I know they will be children of init process but who will call wait on them? (else we are in trouble and limited with PIDs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know they will be children of init process but who will call wait on them?

`init` (process with PID 1) will reap all of its child processes, including adpoted zombie processes. As it says on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

> init periodically executes the wait system call to reap any zombies
> with init as parent.